Intertwiner space isomorphism with invariante space

Let $V,W$ be two representation vector spaces of some group $G$. Thus,
an intertwiner is as a linear map $T:V\rightarrow W$ satisfying $$ T(g\cdot v)=g\cdot T(v) $$ We'll denote the space of intertwiners by
$\text{Hom}_G(V,W)$
Then, a useful result it the following isomorphism
$$\text{Hom}_G(V,W)\simeq \text{Inv}_G(V\otimes W^*) $$ where $W^*$ is
the dual space of $W$ and $$\text{Inv}_G(E)=\{\psi \in E: \forall g\in
 G, g\cdot \psi = \psi\}$$
Page 15, book: A primer of group theory for LQG - Pierre Dussaud

I'm trying to prove this result given by the author or find some reference about it but I can't find any. I'd be grateful for any help on this.

I will use the notation $V^G$ for the invariants of a $G$-rep $V$.
Tensor-Hom Relation. There is an isomorphism $V^\ast\otimes W\to\hom(V,W)$ where any pure element $\varphi\otimes w$ corresponds to the linear transformation $v\mapsto \varphi(v)w$. If you pick bases for $V$ and $W$, you can write elements as column vectors, in which case $V^\ast$ consists of row vectors and $\varphi(v)$ corresponds to $\varphi^T v$, and then the isomorphism is simply matrix multiplication $\varphi^T\otimes w\mapsto w\varphi^T$.
Action on Tensors and Homs. If $V$ is a $G$-rep, then so is $V^\ast$ with the contragredient action $(g\cdot\varphi)(v):=\varphi(g^{-1}v)$, and if $W$ is an $H$-rep, then $V^\ast\otimes W$ and $\hom(V,W)$ are both $G\times H$-reps. The action on the former is given by $(g,h)(\varphi\otimes w)=(g\cdot\varphi)\otimes hw$ and similarly the action on the latter is given by $((g,h)f)(v)=hf(g^{-1}v)$. In other words, the groups act on each factor of $V^\ast\otimes W$ independently, and act on $\hom(V,W)$ by pre- and post-composition by operators on $V$ and $W$.
Tensor-Hom Equivalence. Observe the vector space isomorphism $V^\ast\otimes W\to\hom(V,W)$ is equivariant, so is an equivalence of $G\times H$-reps. This can be checked directly: first apply $(g,h)$ to $\varphi\otimes w$ in $V^\ast\otimes W$ and apply the result to $v\in V$, then (separately) apply $(g,h)$ to the function $v\mapsto \varphi(v)w$ in $\hom(V,W)$. See the final product is the same either way.
When $H=G$ we have a diagonal embedding $G\to G\times G$ (that is, $g\mapsto (g,g)$), and restricting the action to this diagonal copy of $G$ makes both $V^\ast\otimes W$ and $\hom(V,W)$ into $G$-reps.
Intertwiners as Invariants. Note $\hom_G(V,W)=\hom(V,W)^G$. This is basically by definition: the intertwiners and invariants are characterized by the relations $T(gv)=gT(v)$ and $gT(g^{-1}v)=T(v)$ (for all $v\in V$ and $g\in G$) respectively; these are equivalent by replacing $g$ with $g^{-1}$ and applying $g$.
Therefore, the intertwiners $\hom_G(V,W)$ are the invariants $\hom(V,W)^G$ which, since there is an equivalence $\hom(V,W)\cong V^\ast\otimes W$ of $G$-reps, correspond to the invariants $(V^\ast\otimes W)^G$.

Thank you! For future readers: the author uses $V \otimes W^$ instead of $V^ \otimes W$. I was not sure if it was an error, but then I found other papers in this area (Spin Networks, Baez 2010, page 21) that use $V^* \otimes W$. With this insightful answer, it makes sense that it was an error.

Ah, I didn't even notice that. Yes, that is an error in the source.
